# Could not download the Silverlight application in SharePoint 2010 Silverlight Viewer WebPart

Tags: sharepoint, silverlight-4.0, sharepoint-2010

I am using Out of the box Silverlight Viewer WebPart in SharePoint 2010 Foundation.

Intermittently (Rather most of the time I would say) it shows following error when the Silverlight Viewer Web Part tries to load the XAP file from path "/_layouts/XAPFileName.xap"

> Could not download the Silverlight application. To re-configure the
>   Web Part or to provide a different Silverlight application (.xap),
>   open the tool pane and then click Configure.

Size of my XAP file is roughly 1.5 MB only.

Alternative solutions I have found are to create asp.net web part for this or use HTM Form View web part as suggested in these articles

http://forums.silverlight.net/p/193392/448263.aspx

http://nareshbojja.wordpress.com/2010/12/02/could-not-download-the-silverlight-application-or-the-silverlight-plugin-did-not-load/

but is not ther a way I can make it work with OOB Silverlight Viewer Web Part itself ?